# Bloomberg Bulk Data Regex Parsing

Tags: regex, bulk, bloomberg

I am trying to parse the result from Bloomberg Data Licence when they return a `bulk data` format.

This string is typically a bunch of key value pairs separated by a semi colon and indicated by a number for the data type they are.

The first three numbers are the fact that it is a 2d array with 4 results. The number before the value is the datatype, e.g. 5 is date and 3 is number, however this is not important right now.

Here is an example data response:
`;2;4;2;5;20181201;3;102;5;20191201;3;101.000000;5;20201201;3;100.000000;5;20211201;3;100.000000;`

Expected return would be to grab the dates and the values from this string, and the result would be:

**20181201** - **102**

**20191201** - **101.000000**

**20201201** - **100.000000**

**20211201** - **100.000000**

I have tried the following regex using replace:

`5;(?P<date>\d{8})|\;3;(?P<value>\w+.\w+)` and using replace value `\1, \2` which returns the following:

`;2;4;2;20181201,,102;5;20191201,101.000000;20201201,,100.000000;20211201,,100.000000;`

I am still getting the return value of `;2;4;2` - how do I ignore these first three grouped values in my regex?

P.S. This is just example data, doesn't actually refer to anything

Comment: there is no `102.5` in the data, but try using lookarounds `(?<=5;)(?P<date>\d{8})|(?<=;3;)(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` https://regex101.com/r/q6vo1V/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for your quick response. I am intrigued with the use of negative look arounds. How do they work exactly?

Comment: There are some very good pages about lookarounds. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and for example https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html. But note that without using the lookarounds, you still get the data in the named capturing groups. https://regex101.com/r/2E9P21/1

Comment: You could also split the string and process each field in order in a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern, you use `\w+.\w+` which matches 1+ word characters, 1 time any char using the dot and again 1+ word characters. It expects to match at least 3 characters.

That is why in the example data you match `102;5` instead of 102 because the dot will match the `;` and the last `\w+` will match the `5`.

---

If you only want the data in the named groups *data* and *value*, you can use lookarounds instead.

To match the digits with an optional decimal parts, you could use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead.

Instead of replacing the values, you should get the match from the group.

```
(?<=5;)(?P<date>\d{8})|(?<=;3;)(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6vo1V/1)